# TicTacToe react - sequence highlighting

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, tic-tac-toe

Can anybody study my code and tell me how to get the sequence highlighted in the Tic Tac Toe game?

Below is my code.

Board.jsx

```
import React, {useState } from "react";
import Square from "../Square/Square";
import classes from "./Board.module.css";

const Board = () =>{

    const [state, setState] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
    const [isXTurn, setIsXTurn] = useState(null);
    const [playerSymbol, setPlayerSymbol] = useState(null);
    const [winningSequence, setWinningSequence] = useState([]);

    const checkWinner = () => {
        const winnerLogic = [
            [0, 1, 2],
            [3, 4, 5],
            [6, 7, 8],
            [0, 3, 6],
            [1, 4, 7],
            [2, 5, 8],
            [0, 4, 8],
            [2, 4, 6]
        ]

        for (let logic of winnerLogic){
            const [a, b, c] = logic;
            if(state[a] != null && state[a] === state[b] && state[a] === state[c]){
                // setWinningSequence([a,b,c])
                // console.log(winningSequence)
                return state[a];
            }
        }
        // setWinningSequence([]);
        return false;
    }

    const isWinner = checkWinner()

    const squareClickHandler = (index) => {
        if (state[index] != null || isWinner){
            return;
        } 
        const copyState = [...state]
        copyState[index] = isXTurn ? "X" : "O"
        setState(copyState);
        setIsXTurn(!isXTurn)
    }

    const handlePlayAgain = () => {
        setState(Array(9).fill(null))
        setIsXTurn(null)
        setPlayerSymbol(null)
        setWinningSequence([])
    }

    const handleSymbolSelection = (symbol) => {
        if (symbol === "X"){
            setIsXTurn(true);
        }else{
            setIsXTurn(false);
        }

        setPlayerSymbol(symbol);
    };

    const renderSymbolSelection = () => {
        return (
            <center>
                <h2>Select Your Symbol</h2>
                <button onClick={() => handleSymbolSelection("X")}>X</button>
                <button onClick={() => handleSymbolSelection("O")}>O</button>
            </center>
        );
    };

    const renderSquare = (index) => {
        // console.log(winningSequence)
        const isWinningSquare = winningSequence.includes(index);
        return (
            <Square
                key={index}
                onClick={() => squareClickHandler(index)}
                value={state[index]}
                isWinningSquare={isWinningSquare}
            />
        );
    };
    

    return (
        <div className={classes["board-container"]}>
            {!playerSymbol ? (
                renderSymbolSelection()
            ) : isWinner ? (
                <>
                 <center>
                     {isWinner} Won the Game <button onClick={handlePlayAgain}>Play Again</button>
                 </center>
                
                <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
                        {renderSquare(0)}
                        {renderSquare(1)}
                        {renderSquare(2)}
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
                        {renderSquare(3)}
                        {renderSquare(4)}
                        {renderSquare(5)}
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
                        {renderSquare(6)}
                        {renderSquare(7)}
                        {renderSquare(8)}
                    </div>
                </>
                
            ) : (
                <>
                    <center>
                        <h4>Player {playerSymbol} please move!</h4>
                    </center>
                    <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
                        {renderSquare(0)}
                        {renderSquare(1)}
                        {renderSquare(2)}
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
                        {renderSquare(3)}
                        {renderSquare(4)}
                        {renderSquare(5)}
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
                        {renderSquare(6)}
                        {renderSquare(7)}
                        {renderSquare(8)}
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};


export default Board;
```

Square.jsx

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import classes from "./Square.module.css";

const Square = ({ value, onClick, isWinningSquare }) => {
    const squareClassName = `${classes.square} ${isWinningSquare ? classes.winning : ""}`;

    return (
        <div className={squareClassName} onClick={onClick}>
            <h2>{value}</h2>
        </div>
    );
};

export default memo(Square);
```

Tried creating a winning sequence state

```
const [winningSequence, setWinningSequence] = useState([]);
```

In the checkWinner function when I try to add the elements in the winningSequence array I'm getting an infinite render error.

Do I need to use something like useEffect or useCallback?

```
for (let logic of winnerLogic){
            const [a, b, c] = logic;
            if(state[a] != null && state[a] === state[b] && state[a] === state[c]){
                // setWinningSequence([a,b,c])
                // console.log(winningSequence)
                return state[a];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fixed example: (No changes made to `Square.js`)

1. Move the winning sequences outside of the components to make them global. (A slight optimization)
2. You are mixing the `isWinner` variable to mean both `isThereAWinner` and `whoIsTheWinner`. This is a hack-y solution, but ok.
3. Use `useEffect` after every state change to actively check winning sequences.
4. Make sure that `.winning` css class is after the default `.square` one in the css if the latter is already setting a background color.

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import classes from "./Board.module.css";
import Square from "./Square";

const winnerLogic = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
];

const Board = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
  const [isXTurn, setIsXTurn] = useState(null);
  const [playerSymbol, setPlayerSymbol] = useState(null);
  const [winningSequence, setWinningSequence] = useState([]);
  const [isWinner, setIsWinner] = useState(null);

  const checkWinner = useCallback(() => {
    for (let logic of winnerLogic) {
      const [a, b, c] = logic;
      if (state[a] != null && state[a] === state[b] && state[a] === state[c]) {
        setWinningSequence([a, b, c]);
        return state[a];
      }
    }
    setWinningSequence([]);
    return false;
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsWinner(checkWinner());
  }, [state, checkWinner]);

  const squareClickHandler = (index) => {
    if (state[index] != null || isWinner) {
      return;
    }
    const copyState = [...state];
    copyState[index] = isXTurn ? "X" : "O";
    setState(copyState);
    setIsXTurn(!isXTurn);
  };

  const handlePlayAgain = () => {
    setState(Array(9).fill(null));
    setIsXTurn(null);
    setPlayerSymbol(null);
    setWinningSequence([]);
  };

  const handleSymbolSelection = (symbol) => {
    if (symbol === "X") {
      setIsXTurn(true);
    } else {
      setIsXTurn(false);
    }

    setPlayerSymbol(symbol);
  };

  const renderSymbolSelection = () => {
    return (
      <center>
        <h2>Select Your Symbol</h2>
        <button onClick={() => handleSymbolSelection("X")}>X</button>
        <button onClick={() => handleSymbolSelection("O")}>O</button>
      </center>
    );
  };

  const renderSquare = (index) => {
    // console.log(winningSequence)
    const isWinningSquare = winningSequence.includes(index);
    console.log(winningSequence.includes(index));
    return (
      <Square
        key={index}
        onClick={() => squareClickHandler(index)}
        value={state[index]}
        isWinningSquare={isWinningSquare}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes["board-container"]}>
      {!playerSymbol ? (
        renderSymbolSelection()
      ) : isWinner ? (
        <>
          <center>
            {isWinner} Won the Game{" "}
            <button onClick={handlePlayAgain}>Play Again</button>
          </center>

          <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
            {renderSquare(0)}
            {renderSquare(1)}
            {renderSquare(2)}
          </div>
          <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
            {renderSquare(3)}
            {renderSquare(4)}
            {renderSquare(5)}
          </div>
          <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
            {renderSquare(6)}
            {renderSquare(7)}
            {renderSquare(8)}
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <center>
            <h4>Player {playerSymbol} please move!</h4>
          </center>
          <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
            {renderSquare(0)}
            {renderSquare(1)}
            {renderSquare(2)}
          </div>
          <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
            {renderSquare(3)}
            {renderSquare(4)}
            {renderSquare(5)}
          </div>
          <div className={classes["board-row"]}>
            {renderSquare(6)}
            {renderSquare(7)}
            {renderSquare(8)}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Board;
```